# how to add the place holder image in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my sample coding try to implement the placeholder image.I fetch my data from internet

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if((imageview!=null)&&(result!=null)){
            ImageView imgview=imageview.get();
             if(imgview!=null){
                 imgview.setImageBitmap(result);
             }
            else{
                 Drawable place=imgview.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_place);
                 imgview.setImageDrawable(place);
             }

        }
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how to add the place holder image ?

Comment: try setting a background color to the imageView e.g (imgview..setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(95, 87, 87));) other wise if you only want image as a placeholderset set a default image in your xml imageview and replace the image with code as you have above in your Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an image, during `onPostExecute`. I am guessing  you are  doing something like fetching the image from a site or something.

Before you start the query, set the image with the code:

```
imgview.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_place));
```

Comment: I think you said to  place that code in  my "onBindViewHolder" method.

Comment: No, sorry, what I meant was: on your code (that is not shown here), BEFORE you start the query that would result in this `onPostExecute`... so, if for instance, you are pressing a button, or populating a view or something, then you set the imageview the placeholder image.

Comment: If this helped you, click the `v` near the arrows on the left. When using stackoverflow, `accepted` answers will pop up, and people with similar issues, can read something that helped fix it first.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look to this library:
https://github.com/square/picasso

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: While Picasso is a good image library, this does not answer the question, and you didnt even explained what it does... There is nothing on the question that ensures that this is a internet fetch. He could be using local data only

Comment: but i am not using picasso.Could you tell me how to use without picasso.

Answer (score 0):

To set Bitmap into ImageView, write this code.

```
ImageView imageview;
imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.(your xml img id));
imageview.setImageBitmap(img);
```

And to set ImageView From resource(Drawable), write this code.

```
ImageView imageview;
imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.(your xml img id));
//here
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(lowerCountryCode, "drawable", getPackageName());
imageview.setImageResource(id);
//or direct by
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
```